# How can access 'in-memory' sqlite database from QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I created an in-memory SQLite database using Qt-C++

```
const QString m_DRIVER = "QSQLITE";
QSqlDatabase m_db;
m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(m_DRIVER, "mkddb");
m_db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
```

My question is how I can access it in QML?

Comment: What a reason to use in-memory DB? You can access Sqlite DB from QML using [LocalStorage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-localstorage-qmlmodule.html#opendatabasesync). Anyway, you can use [common way](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html) to expose C++ class to QML and so access your DB.

Comment: @folibis It really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as You have the database connection established in some class of Yours, eg. `Database Handler`, You can expose it to QML in a very simple way. Here is a very brief concept of how such handler would look like:

DatabaseHandler.h

```
class DatabaseHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DatabaseHandler(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE void addDatabaseEntry(QString queryString);

private:
    QSqlDatabase database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "mkddb");
    QSqlQuery databaseQuery;
};
```

DatabaseHandler.cpp

```
DatabaseHandler::DatabaseHandler(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    database.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
    database.open();
    databaseQuery = QSqlQuery(database);
}

void DatabaseHandler::addDatabaseEntry(QString queryString)
{
    databaseQuery.exec(queryString);
}
```

The object itself has to be a `QObject` with a `Q_OBJECT` macro as on the code above.

To expose the `DatabaseHandler` to QML,  in eg. `main.cpp` You would have to write this:

```
qmlRegisterType<DatabaseHandler>("com.organization.databasehandler", 1, 0, "DatabaseHandler");
```

Then in QML code You can import the database handler and use its methods **as long as they're declared with the macro** `Q_INVOKABLE` like in the `DatabaseHandler.h`:

```
import com.organization.databasehandler 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    DatabaseHandler {
        id: databaseHandler
    }

    Button {
        onClicked: databaseHandler.addDatabaseEntry(/*Query to execute on the database*/)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution saved me a day. I applied it to my problem and it worked very well.

Comment: Very nice to hear that! Good luck with the project :D Oh, and can You, please mark my answer as accepted? My account is quite new and lacking reputation, so I can't for example upvote posts and You would help me with that :)

Comment: I upvoted your answer but my reputation is low and as a result, my vote does not appear until I reach 15 reputations.

Comment: Oh, I know, but I meant `accepting` an answer, which is clicking the ✔ button :)